# How to filter product collection by matching string like search in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, catalogsearch

We have loaded product collection based on category ID, we are further trying to filter the product collection result with query string.

We have tried :

Query string `set` and `get` is working fine with below code.

```
$query = $this->_queryFactory->create();
$query->setQueryText('Joust');
$query->getQueryText();
```

Add search filter is not working to my product collection.

```
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection;

$collection->addSearchFilter($query->getQueryText());
```

Can any one help me on this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addSearchFilter` does not do much if you don't apply the filter:

```
public function addSearchFilter($query)
{
    $this->queryText = trim($this->queryText . ' ' . $query);
    return $this;
}
```

What you need to do is to inject `\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder`, `\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder`  as well as `\Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface` and do the following:

```
$this->filterBuilder->setField('search_term');
$this->filterBuilder->setValue('Joust');
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$searchCriteria->setRequestName("search");
$this->searchResult = $this->searchInterface->search($searchCriteria);
```

Comment: if we join custom table and need to add that custom table column for search how to do it ?  that is think there is custom table with FK product id  and custom sku  if customer search with custom sku the result should also display how to do it?

Comment: Getting error "Request name 'search' doesn't exist." at line $this->searchInterface->search($searchCriteria);

Comment: @Raphael Can you plz help look at my question. I'm trying to truncate the search query https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311115/magento-2-truncate-search-term-in-quick-search-if-the-last-4-digits-are-number

Comment: @Magecode did you find a solution to this? Removing the line doesn’t fix the issue because I get `Request name not defined`.

Comment: It works if I use `"quick_search_container"` instead but I don’t know why

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work how exactly?

**The collection results do not change?**

If the collection is loaded, than no amount of filtering will have effect on the results.

You would have to clear the collection and load it again:

```
$collection->clear();
$collection->load();
```

Or add the filters before it gets loaded.

**Is the collection returning no or incorrect results?**

Have a look at the addSearchFilter function and check what is content of the queryText

```
public function addSearchFilter($query)
{
    $this->queryText = trim($this->queryText . ' ' . $query);
    return $this;
}
```

You can always look directly at the query and see if there are issues:

```
var_dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
```